# Editing D3 Tooltip html in d3-tip

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have some tooltips on points in a D3 map & on load I specify the HTML content of the tooltips with the following snippet:

```
var tip = d3.tip()
    .attr('class', 'd3-tip')
    .offset([-10, 0])
    .html(function (d) { return d.name });
```

`d.name` refers to a header value in the CSV which contains the lat/longs and where it pulls the data from.

There is a second header in the JSON called `Property_A`. I want to create a function whereby the user can alter which field is displayed in the tooltip. I've got the headers all in an array, I just can't seem to change them.

I've tried putting this on a function of its own:

```
    d3.select("#tip").html(function (d) { return d.Property_A });
```

However, it doesn't do anything (not even an error in console), & the tips keep returning the name field.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I've not used d3-tip much, but I would imagine that the function provided to d3.tip().hml() is called each time the tip is shown - so if you set it to something else, that text is overwritten by d3-tip anyways (also, given the lack of supporting code, it's not clear what `d` is in the second code block in any event, possibly undefined, or when you call that code - is it in a mouseover function?). You could probably specify `d3.tip().html(function(d) { return d[property] })` where `property` is the name of the current property the user wants to show.

Comment: As an [example](http://bl.ocks.org/Andrew-Reid/raw/bbfc2cdb06be863c5c8f6fee46b17646/), based on [this demo of d3-tip (v3)](http://bl.ocks.org/Caged/6476579)